When building qemu through yocto error: ../target/hexagon/meson.build:29:16: ERROR: No build machine compiler for 'target/hexagon/gen_semantics.c'
I'm trying to enable support for am62xx-evm machine through yocto. here is my recipe:
SUMMARY = "QEMU for aarch64 architecture"
DESCRIPTION = "QEMU for emulating the aarch64 architecture, fetched from upstream Git."

LICENSE = "GPLv2 & LGPLv2.1"
LIC_FILES_CHKSUM = "file://LICENSE;md5=6541297aed25bfd5e8d893ea097e838c"


SRC_URI = "git://gitlab.com/qemu-project/qemu.git;protocol=https"
SRC_URI += "file:///home/jenkins/dev/mkonov/dtc/dtc"

SRCREV = "134b443512825bed401b6e141447b8cdc22d2efe"

DEPENDS = "flex-native bison-native meson pkgconfig pkgconfig-native glib-2.0 libftdi pixman zlib ninja-native"


S = "${WORKDIR}/git"


do_configure() {

    ./configure
}

do_compile() {
    oe_runmake
}

do_install() {
    install -d ${D}${bindir}
    install -m 0755 qemu-system-aarch64 ${D}${bindir}/qemu-system-aarch64
}

As you can see, I want it to run the configure script in qemu.
The error I get is as after it finishes executing the subproject keycodemapdb and it's as follows:
| Executing subproject keycodemapdb
|
| keycodemapdb| Project name: keycodemapdb
| keycodemapdb| Project version: undefined
| keycodemapdb| Program tools/keymap-gen found: YES (/home/jenkins/dev/yocto/poky/qemu_build/tmp/work/aarch64-poky-linux/qemu-system-aarch64-recipe/1.0-r0/git/subprojects/keycodemapdb/tools/keymap-gen)
| keycodemapdb| Build targets in project: 349
| keycodemapdb| Subproject keycodemapdb finished.
|
| Program scripts/decodetree.py found: YES (/home/jenkins/dev/yocto/poky/qemu_build/tmp/work/aarch64-poky-linux/qemu-system-aarch64-recipe/1.0-r0/git/build/pyvenv/bin/python3 /home/jenkins/dev/yocto/poky/qemu_build/tmp/work/aarch64-poky-linux/qemu-system-aarch64-recipe/1.0-r0/git/scripts/decodetree.py)
|
| ../target/hexagon/meson.build:29:16: ERROR: No build machine compiler for 'target/hexagon/gen_semantics.c'
|
| A full log can be found at /home/jenkins/dev/yocto/poky/qemu_build/tmp/work/aarch64-poky-linux/qemu-system-aarch64-recipe/1.0-r0/git/build/meson-logs/meson-log.txt
|
| ERROR: meson setup failed
|
| WARNING: exit code 1 from a shell command.
ERROR: Task (/home/jenkins/dev/yocto/poky/meta-tisdk-qemu/recipes-core/qemu-system-aarch64-recipe/qemu-system-aarch64-recipe.bb:do_configure) failed with exit code '1'

I tried adding gcc, g++, cmake, make,bison, flex to dependencies but it changed nothing. I tracked down the gen_semantics.c file - https://gricad-gitlab.univ-grenoble-alpes.fr/michelse/qemu/-/blob/master/target/hexagon/gen_semantics.c?ref_type=heads
but it gave me no information

The error message from meson is
No build machine compiler for 'target/hexagon/gen_semantics.c'

That means that the environment you're building QEMU in is missing the C compiler that targets that host architecture (usually this is an x86 compiler). Note that this is different from the C compiler that targets the eventual target architecture (which might be a cross-compiler).
That said, the error message is for a part of QEMU you don't seem to care about and you can also avoid it by telling configure to build only what you do care about, rather than its default of "build everything possible".
If you only care about building qemu-system-aarch64 you can pass configure the option --target-list=aarch64-softmmu. This will make it build much faster because it doesn't build all the possible guest architectures. In particular it won't try to build hexagon so will probably avoid the problem you're seeing.

Even though I used that option, it still didn't build and stopped at the same error. What I found that fixes the error is changing the do_configure() command:
do_configure() {
export CC="${CROSS_COMPILE}gcc"
export CXX="${CROSS_COMPILE}g++"
export LD="${CROSS_COMPILE}ld"
export AR="${CROSS_COMPILE}ar"
./configure --target-list=aarch64-softmmu

}
This goes past all of those errors and finishes the whole configuration file, but when running the make command, it stops with an error at the 200th task. I don't know if the two errors are related

That is not a correct fix, because it says "you can build code to run on the host by running the cross-compiler". Eventually the build will try to run that code it built with the cross compiler, and it will fall over. You need to install the host C compiler, in whatever way is the correct way to do that for Yocto.
